# XCode7 UI testing with multiple devices

Tags: ios, xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing XCUITests for my app. For basic scenarios I am able to write tests.

But I am not able to write for following scenario .
My app is like a chatting application where my app from device1 sends message to my app on device2.

I want to test this scenario end to end with xcode7-ui-testing, I could not figure out anyone way.

Can anyone please help me how can I achieve it with xcode7-ui-testing or any other method/framework ?

Comment: you could add a second UI tests target with test cases for the second device.

Comment: Can you elaborate how and how can I run multiple test targets separately ?

Comment: Duplicate the scheme, xcode is currently using and use one for each device, edit both: Edit Scheme>Test>select the tests for each device, select first scheme and run on first device, select second scheme and run on second device.